# How to show all dates (jubilees) from contacts on calendar

Tags: calendar, contacts

There is 1 calendar, that shows only birthday dates from contacts on iphone/mac OS. But if 1 contact has several dates (e.g. jubilee, birthday of kids or other important dates) that i want to be shown in calendar on iphone or mac OS.
How can it be done? And can it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. You can add custom dates in Contacts

[image]

and create repeating events in Calendar,

[image]

but there's no automatic linkage between the two. The best you'll get is something like [BirthdayScanner](http://www.zencat.de/bsx/index.html) which scans *all* dates in Contacts then allows you to add them to your Calendar, but there's no first-party automagic solution.